# Retrieve user data from Firestore where id is equalTo

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My request gives me a result but I can't display the information in a Text Widget or other, what can I do?
Here is a screenshot of my code:
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0d6d.png)

Here is the result in the console:
[Result in Concole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbO7z.png)

Comment: Please include codes. Images of codes are hard to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here documentData is a list of map.. so you have to access the child by its index

```dart
documentData[0]['nom'] //for example
```